# unreadable downloaded text

Tags: c#

downloaded a text file using WebClient.DownloadString
the downloaded string is unreadable. the encoding must be wrong.

how can i convert it to a readable string, what method do i need to use?

i don't know which encoding it is.

Comment: How do you mean "unreadable"? Can you show a sample of what it looks like, and what you expect to get?

Comment: "��W\0e\0b\0 \0S\0e\0a\0r\0c\0h\0 \0I\0n\.........

Comment: You'll have to find out what the encoding is. That said, the example you posted looks a little like UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like LiveHTTPHeaders in firefox you'll be able to see the encoding that is being used - if it's a web page!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert the returned string back to a byte[] (Using whatever WebClient.Encoding is set) then using a streamreader to read it back in. I'm not sure how much checking DownloadString tries to do (Though it would appear to be none), but the streamreader will attempt to detect encoding [up to a point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569610.aspx#Question2).